# Websocket - sockjs - InvalidStateError: The connection has not been established yet

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, stomp, sockjs

When using stomp.js and sockjs from within Javascript, I can connect well with a Spring Boot backend.

When using stompjs and sockjs from with Angular5, I keep on getting these errors:

InvalidStateError: The connection has not been established yet

Is there a workaround? Just adding the sockjs.min.js, [as mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40057710/3143823), was not helping.

The detailed log is:

> Setting up connection/1 main.3388a5e3a20e64e3bdb8.bundle.js:1 Setting
>   up connection/2 main.3388a5e3a20e64e3bdb8.bundle.js:1 Going to
>   subscribe ...  main.3388a5e3a20e64e3bdb8.bundle.js:1 Opening Web
>   Socket... main.3388a5e3a20e64e3bdb8.bundle.js:1 >>> SEND
>   destination:/app/chat.addUser content-length:29
>
> {"sender":"me","type":"JOIN"} main.3388a5e3a20e64e3bdb8.bundle.js:1
>   ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidStateError: The
>   connection has not been established yet Error: InvalidStateError: The
>   connection has not been established yet
>       at r.send (scripts.d6f701ecf84f24372966.bundle.js:1)

My code in Angular (translated from Javascript) is:

```
 let ws = new SockJS(this.serverUrl);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
    let that = this;
    console.log('Setting up connection/2');
    console.log('Going to subscribe ... ');
    this.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
      console.log('Going to subscribe ... ');
      that.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/public', (payload) => {
          console.log('Subscribe: Incoming message: ' + payload.body);
          if (payload.body) {
            let message = JSON.parse(payload.body);
            if (message.sender === 'MyBot') {
              this.createAndAddChat('you', message.content);
            } else {
              this.createAndAddChat('me', message.content);
            }
            console.log('New message arrived: ' + payload.body);
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log( 'Subscribe: error: ' + error)
        },
        () => {
         console.log( 'Subscribe, On complete')
        });
    });
    this.stompClient.send("/app/chat.addUser", {},
      JSON.stringify({sender: 'me', type: 'JOIN'})
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The send method is now called directly after starting (!) the asynchronous get-connection call. That's wrong.

There are 2 solutions:

- Good: Put the send call within the async-body of the get-connection. So after the connection is made, call the send method.
- Not optimal: Wait for some time to have the async get-connection to complete.

Comment: what does it mean exactly? could you anyone tell me how to fix it.?

Comment: The error is:  The connection has not been established yet.
Looking back for the solution of 2 years ago, I see that at first the async get-connection method is called. Without waiting for it to complete, I directly started with the send method. That's not correct. Option 1: [1] allow time for the connection or better [2] have the send method called when the connection is finished.

Answer (score 1):

```
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        setTimeout(function() {
           stompClient.subscribe("/topic/mytopic/", function (message) {
              showDeviceConnection(deviceIds[i], message.body);
           });
        }, 500);});
```

Comment: Kindly consider explaining, if possible, where and what your solution does. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the connection has been established, before subscribing to your Spring boot topic. use useState to set Topics array in SockJs in onConnect().

Here is how i solved the issue:

```
const [topics, setTopics] = useState([]);

const onConnected = () => {
    //console.log("Connected!!");
    setTopics(['/topic/message']);
}

const onMessageReceived = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
}

return (
   <SockJsClient
        url='http://localhost:8080/ws-message'
        topics={topics}
        onConnect={onConnected}
        onMessage={data=> onMessageReceived(data)}
        debug={true}
   />
)
```

Hope this will answer the question